# .htaccess for extra domain and HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have main domain and an extra domain.

Question:

1. When surfing to:

   ```
   ftp.addondomain.com
   ```

   or

   ```
   mail.addondomain.com
   ```

   For some reason it goes to the main domain (normally this should not be problem but I still want completely separation), do you know the syntax to redirect in the .htaccess file this:

   ```
   (.*).addondomain.com
   ```

   To:

   ```
   addondomain.com
   ```

   And where do I put the code in the extra domain `.htaccess` or in the main domain `,htaccess`?

   I.E `any_words.addondomain.com` should be forwarded to the `extradomain.com` so  `dsdhf.addondomain.com ftp.addondomain.com mail.addondomain.com` all will be forwarded to `addondomain.com` (i.e without the prefix).
2. Same question for HTTPS Main domain has SSL addon domain does not have SSL.

   For some reason when surfing to `https://extradomain.com` you get to `http://maindomain.com` (the address bar shows `https://extradomain.com` but the site pages - the page you see is the page of the main domain)

   I would like that if user surfs to `https://extradomain.com` then (since there is no SSL for the extra domain) then user will get to: `http://extradomain.com` or alternatively user will get error message. I do not want him to be redirected to the main domain.

If you can, write me what to add to the `.htaccess` and I will add it.

Comment: "addondomain" is confusing.  It could mean either foo.domain.com, or other.com.  Please clarify.  In any case, this smells more like a dns issue than an htaccess issue. Also, htaccess is for directory-specific updates. For something like this, you will most likely want to put the directives inside a <directory> tag on the server config (assuming, of course, you have access to said config).

Comment: Hi. Site is on shard host (lunarpages).
With lunarpages you can have 1 main domain per host + addon domains.
when i write addon domain i mean to a domain like domain.com  i.e real domain (not sub domain) that is forwarded but lunarpages to a folder on the host - so use sees it as regular domain.

Comment: [Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider reading **the SO Tour**. it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: @admon addon domain on cPanel is merely an alias to your main domain which is why all that happens. You will not be able to fully make it part away but you can do to some extent, if you post your domain .htaccess we might be able to help you since we will have to see what has been done in order to know what we will have to write or rewrite for the addon.

Comment: .htaccess is empty for both the main domain and the addon domain.
lunarpages do not put anything to the domain or to the addon domain .htaccess when creating addon domain